# Interceptors - How to find the owner of previous snapshot in onCollectionUpdate?

Tags: java, hibernate, interceptor

So I have overridden the 'onCollectionUpdate' method from Hibernate Interceptor, in order to audit collection change in an entity.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCollectionUpdate(Object collection, Serializable key) throws CallbackException {
    if (collection != null) {
        PersistentCollection persistentColl = ((PersistentCollection) collection);
        Object owner = persistentColl.getOwner();
        Class<?> obj = owner.getClass();
        if (obj.isAnnotationPresent( AuditTrail.class )) {

            Map previousStoredSnapshotMap = (Map) persistentColl.getStoredSnapshot();
            Object previousCollOrMap;
            if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom( collection.getClass() )) {
                previousCollOrMap = previousStoredSnapshotMap.values();
            } else {
                previousCollOrMap = previousStoredSnapshotMap;
            }
            String propertyName = persistentColl.getRole().substring( persistentColl.getRole().lastIndexOf( '.' ) + 1 );

            try {

                AuditTrail auditTrail = obj.getAnnotation( AuditTrail.class );
                if (auditTrail.trail()) {
                    //logging method to be added here
                }

            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have found the "owner" - current state of a parent object. But how can I get the previous owner (the owner of previousStoredSnapshot)?

Thanks

Comment: `How can If find the previous owner` implies you are swapping the owner of a collection and want to track that? Please show some code demonstrating the kind of change to a collection you want to intercept.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to track the collection change inside an object.

   public class Site{
...private Set<Premise>           premises;...
}

So my entity is Site and it has a collection of premises inside.
When premises are updated, interceptor catches that change (code above) and then I can compare the old and the new version of collection. I can also get the current state of Site entity -  Object owner = persistentColl.getOwner(); Now I need the same thing for previousCollOrMap , but I can't cast HashMap to PersistentCollection as I did with new collection.